# Why does typeof(0) return boolean instead of number

Tags: javascript, typeof

I have problem with JavaScript conversion. Here is an example:

```
var obj = {
    x: 0,
    y: 1,
    z: 2
}

var b1 = typeof (obj.x),
    b2 = typeof (obj.y),
    b3 = typeof (obj.z);
```

b1 is `"boolean"`, b2 is `"boolean"`, b3 is `"number"`.

I need to set variable to 0 and I need JavaScript to interpret it as a number. I've tried with conversions such as b1 = Number("0") but it doesn't help.

Sorry for the question above. It's true, b1, b2 and b3 all return number. This is my actual problem.

```
var SomeClass = function () {}
SomeClass.prototype = {
    element: {},
    startAt: 0,
    length: 2,
    get: function (prop) {
        if (typeof (prop) === "undefined" || !(typeof (prop) === "string")) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!this[prop]) {
            return false;
        }
        return this[prop];
    }
}

var sc = new SomeClass();
alert(typeof (sc.get("startAt")) + "\n" + typeof (sc.get("length")) + "\n" + typeof (sc.get("element")));
```

I would like to set startAt as an number.

Comment: I just tried it... And it doesn't at all say "boolean".

Comment: Chrome disagrees with your report. What browser / environment are you using?

Comment: *"b1 is "boolean", b2 is "boolean", b3 is "number""* [I beg to differ](http://jsbin.com/eraqef/1). According to the spec, all three should be `"number"`, and are in the tests I run. I've tried Chrome, IE (old and new), Firefox, Opera...

Comment: @ZiyaoWei I doubt there is a javascript engine with this behavior. The problem must be in OP's code.

Comment: @AleksanderFras If you put it into a conditional statement ie. `if(0) { … }`, then `0` is evaluated to `false` and `1` is evaluated to `true`.

Comment: @sweetamylase: Yes, that's true. But that's not what the OP said he's seeing.

Comment: Just an FYI for him...in case he's using it elsewhere and expected something else.

Comment: How do you know `b1` is boolean? Did you print it out? `console.log(b1)`.

Comment: I am [voting to leave this question closed from review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/35218900) as not reproducible because `typeof(0)` results in `number` and not `boolean`, so I am unable to reproduce this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to set startAt as an number.

`SomeClass.prototype.startAt` **is** a number (`0`).

Your `get` function explicitly returns `false` if the property is "falsey":

```
if(!this[prop]){return false;}
```

In JavaScript, `0`, `""`, `false`, `undefined`, and `null` are all "falsey", and so the condition above will be true and cause `get` to return `false`.

If your goal is to return `false` if the property *doesn't exist*, you can do that like this:

```
if (!(prop in this)) { return false; }
```

That will check if the property exists on the object itself *or* its prototype, which I suspect is what you want. But if you only want to check the object itself and ignore properties on the prototype, that would be:

```
if (!this.hasOwnProperty(prop)) { return false; }
```

Bringing that all together, if your goal is for `get` to return `false` for properties that the object doesn't have (either its own, or via its prototype), then:

```
get : function(prop){
          if (typeof prop !== "string" || !(prop in this)) {
            return false;
          }
          return this[prop];
      }
```

I've done a few things there:

1. `typeof` is an operator, not a function, so you don't use parens around its operand (normally)
2. Since `"undefined"` is `!== "string"`, there's no need to check for it specifically when checking that `prop` is a string.
3. I used `!(prop in this)` to see if the object (or its prototype) has the property.
4. I combined the two conditions that returned `false` into a single `if` statement using `||`.